# how to limit checkbox selection in contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a checkbox field in Contact form 7 with 12 options and i want users to select only upto 3 fields only. How is this possible?

I used this code

```
jQuery(function(){
var max = 3;
var checkboxes = jQuery('.checkbox-field-name input[type="checkbox"]');

checkboxes.change(function(){
var current = checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
checkboxes.filter(':not(:checked)').prop('disabled', current >= max);
});
});
```

but not working

Comment: do you get any errors in console?

Comment: Nope. Didn't get any error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add checkbox-field-name as a class or replace js with whatever class you have used
[checkbox checkbox-field-name class:checkbox-field-name use_label_element "item 1" "item 2" "item 3" "item 4" "item 5"]

Comment: The code is not clear, please provide some code or improve the formatting.